# How to use android alarm manager in order to navigate to an alarm page

Tags: flutter, alarmmanager

I want to schedule an alarm which will navigate towards a page where there is a button to turn off the alarm.
This is the code:

```
  static Future<void> triggerAlarm() async {
    developer.log("ALARM");
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => PuzzleSelect(onAddToAlarm: () {},)),
    );
  }
```

Using `context` is not possible, as instance members can't be accessed from a static method